# Guardar array aleatorio de dos dimensiones en un archivo csv (numpy)

Tags: python, array, csv, numpy

Necesito hacer un array aleatorio separado por comas para pasar a un archivo csv pero al intentar se me genera un array sin comas:

```
def generar_matriz():
  datos=int(input('Ingrese la cantidad de datos a generar para la columnas: '))
  matriz=np.random.random((datos+1,4))*100
  print(matriz)
  for i in range(4):
    matriz[0][i]=i+1
  print(matriz)
  np.savetxt("Datos generados.csv", matriz, delimiter = ",")
```

Al pasar a csv con la función np.savetext, se llena el archivo pero todo queda en una columna en vez de cuatro como quería plantear... ejemplo:

```
1.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00
6.506467543860787828e+01,5.183428226432330632e+01,6.309754193719630422e+00,5.235724202633919333e+01
2.288144280904451477e+01,6.562242867752252096e+01,4.169160598311007249e+01,9.749615460977024028e+00
4.052256030490369909e+01,9.940564602550217899e+01,6.657752526068033205e+01,9.800671923486196135e+01
7.895219105919754554e+01,3.807242655005449450e+00,5.546612985964816112e-01,2.320573298719375011e-01
5.776609910915286861e+00,5.396513716044769637e+01,6.671551295821788585e+01,3.355787168261523590e+01
7.519054998556528346e+01,9.808439580156920101e+01,7.232127895867112954e+01,6.316216414232847143e+01
1.245901956734024552e+01,1.651424525004336985e+01,3.544924662223505152e+01,2.496042105879983097e+01
```

Comment: Por favor añade tu código completo y correcto para que sea más fácil ayudarte, con lo que has puesto el código no es reproducible, por problemas de identación, y un return cuando no hay ninguna función definida.

Comment: Ya lo modifiqué, tienes razón gracias

Comment: pero sigues sin tener la identación correcta, y no hay ninguna función definida en el código por que haces un `return`.

Comment: Es que mi código hace otras cosas, ese return es para otra función en la que tengo que hacer una gráfica pero no lo considero importante como para adjuntarlo ya que la verdad es algo largo para lo que quiero

Comment: Por favor te recomiendo leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ya que está siendo difícil ayudarte, en una pregunta que si la pones bien desde el principio, ya podría estar resuelta hace una hora. Por favor lee, este link que te he adunjuntado, y después edita la pregunta. No tiene sentido que pongas un `return` sin un `def` cuando lanzo tu código me da error.

Comment: Por otro lado a donde te trato de llevar, es que el código que has puesto, estándo bien identado y con las sintaxis correcta, te genera un `.csv` separado por comas, por lo que no tendrías ningún error. De hecho en el propio ejemplo que adjuntas (haces muy bien poniendo este ejemplo, sirve de mucha utilidad a los que intentamos ayudar) aparecen claramente las comas.

Comment: Es que no genero mensaje de error lo que pasa es que me da un output inesperado, haciendo que el archivo csv tenga una sola columna en vez de cuatro

Comment: Lo único que necesito es un método para generar un array aleatorio cuyos elementos estén separados por coma ya que por el método numpy.random.random se me genera un array separado por espacios dando lugar al error anterior. No puedo poner todo el código ya que el foro restringe poner tanto código

Comment: Me estaré explicando mal, no sé como hacer que me entiendas. Lo siento, no puedo ayudarte

Comment: Último intento, si no ya fue... igual gracias por intentar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116781/discussion-between-rubiales-alberto-and-juan-felipe-marquez-hernandez).

Comment: Descargar el csv y abrirlo depronto te permitirá ver a que me refiero. Tengo un array 2d pero por alguna razón lo toma como uno de 1d